# How to get the value in textfield of ckeditor in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ckeditor

I have used ckeditor in my asp.net webpage. Now the user will insert a textfield and enter some value in it. Then he submits the form... now at the server side how can I retrieve the value entered in that textfield ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I looked at the CKEditor site and the docs seem a bit lite, and so the Object Browser is your friend in cases like this - it's a great way to examine the controls and components in your project to learn the interface in a "hands on" kind of way.

Answer (score 1):

Should be in CKEditor1.Text depending on what you called it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to provide 'TextboxName.Text' in order to retrieve the submitted values.