# How to get ckeditors value from wpf webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, web, ckeditor, webbrowser-control

So im working on my final school project for software engineer. And my project was some kind of cms that lets people to add their own post to my application. I have this unknown way which is really slowing down my work. 
    The unknown way is:
-I want to get the instance value of ckeditor inside my webbrowser.

I have tried to load php file to webbrowser but its no good.

here is my source code in the add post form:

```
public add_post()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        W1.Navigate("C:\\Users\\AkihiroKisaragi\\source\\repos\\Application_Tutor\\Application_Tutor\\newpost.php");
        MainWindow w = new MainWindow();
        w.buttonmenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

and this is the basic code to the html:

[image: Click here to view the html file]

Summary:

> i just want to know the way to get the value of ckeditor in the
>   webbrowser from the c# codes..

thankyou in advance

Comment: Why do you have a stray `</form> tag ?

Comment: and where is this ckeditor value being stored initially ?

Comment: Use CKEditor as control and then get value using editor1.Text property of CKEditor, let me know if this works !

Comment: the </form> tag is just a leftover random code XD
and i store the js of ckeditor in the software local files.
im sorry but how to use it as control?

Comment: for effective solutions you need to post what is the Java script as well

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments you could try the below snippet on the code behind

```
public add_post()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        W1.Navigate("C:\\Users\\AkihiroKisaragi\\source\\repos\\Application_Tutor\\Application_Tutor\\newpost.php");
        MainWindow w = new MainWindow();
        w.buttonmenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        String ckText = editor1.Text;
        String ckValue = editor1.Value;

    }
```

---

**References:**

[How to get contents of CKEDITOR when postingback in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379548/how-to-get-contents-of-ckeditor-when-postingback-in-asp-net)

[How to get the value in textfield of ckeditor in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467647/how-to-get-the-value-in-textfield-of-ckeditor-in-asp-net)

Comment: Im sorry but syntax ckeditor 1 is not defined.. i cant get ckeditor1.text because ckeditor1 is inside of w1(webbrowser)

Comment: In your `<Script>` tag you have declared it as "editor1"

Comment: since i cant load php file in webbrowser i want to take the ckeditor value from the webbrowser to editable variable in c#

Comment: Have you tried using a Textbox and then obtaining the value from Textbox ?